# Загрузка диска 100% базой данных sql server 2019

Tags: sql-server, dicom

Есть windows 10, sql server 2019. Используется для как dicom server. На диске С(SSD) лежат индексы обследований МРТи сама база данных, а на диске D лежат изображения этих обследований.
2 года всё работало нормально, но началась проблема. Не понятно почему SSD начинает грузится на 100% и перестаёт работать сервер как надо( не удаётся с него снимки выгрузить).
Перезапуск службы sql снимает нагрузку на диск, но работоспособность не возвращается. Помогает на время только полный перезапуск сервера.
Что можно посмотреть в sql server, чтобы вычислить почему такое происходит?
Буду рад любым советам.

Comment: Сервер часом не Hipax? 

Начать можно с профилирования запросов и просмотра логов, чтобы понять, чем именно таким интересным решила заняться база, что загрузила диск работой.

и также желательно посмотреть, сколько на SSD свободного места, и как у него с ресурсом - а то вдруг это десктопный SSD под серверной нагрузкой  и ему уже куку.

Comment: не hipax. у меня eFilm.  В том и дело что по логам ничего такого не вижу(ну или я просто не знаю, что оно может влиять), на ссд ещё свободно 300гб, с ресурсом норм.

Comment: https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/sql-server-monitoring-tools/ вам в помощь